# Packages appear on the launchpad website, but are not recognised by apt

Tags: apt, ppa, launchpad

In the following [launchpad pag](https://launchpad.net/~team-xbmc/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+index?field.series_filter=bionic&batch=200)e of the Kodi stable ppa I see a package named `kodi-game-libretro-snes9x` in the "Overview of published packages" list.

After adding the ppa, I can't install it. It simply does not exits:

```
$ apt search kodi-game-libretro-s
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
kodi-game-libretro-stella/bionic,now 3.9.3.4-1~bionic amd64 [installed]
  Atari - 2600 (Stella) core for kodi's retroplayer
```

I am running Ubuntu 18.4 so I think the launchpad page I linked is correct for my system.

Same thing with some other packages. Is this an issue on my side, or does the package maintainer need to fix this?I there a non hacky way to install these packages anyway?

Comment: Have you done and `apt-get update`? What does `apt policy kodi-game-libretro-s` say?

Comment: @AlexP `$ apt policy kodi-game-libretro-snes9x
N: Unable to locate package kodi-game-libretro-snes9x` and yes I did an update.